# Is it recommended to use Ternary operator?

Tags: c++

In C, we could use ternary like

```
( a == 4) ? a = b: a = 5;
```

Someone told me better not using it, how do you think?

Comment: It's really bad for readability

Comment: It's really good for readability :) Maybe it's readability is a measure of the readers acquaintance to programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conditional operators is useful for forming *expressions*. Use it when you need an expression which depends, well, on a condition. Don't use it to make *statements*. For example, your code could be a statement:

```
if (a == 4) { a = b; }
else        { a = 5; }
```

Or you could write it with a conditional expression, but idiomatically like this:

```
a = (a == 4 ? b : 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should write

```
a = (a == 4) ? b : 5;
```

And that discussion about ternary ops has always seemed quite sterile to me - a couple of good insights can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/ternary-operator-considered-harmful) (TL;DR OP's example:

```
return (a<b) ? (b<c) ? b : (a<c) ? c : a : (a<c) ? a : (b<c) ? c : b;
```

is probably a case where using the ternary operation is not a good idea, in cases like yours it contributes to readability if you ask me).

Answer (score 1):

That is a bad way to use the ternary operator (there are worse ways, but that one is bad). You should use:

```
a = (a == 4) ? b : 5;
```

The difference is that this is clearly an assignment to `a` and the ternary operator determines the value to assign.  In your version, you have to look at the insides of the ternary operator to see that it is assigning to `a` in both branches.  (One of the worse ways of using the ternary operator would be `(a == 4) ? a = b : b = 5;` assigning to two different variables.)

If you feel the need to write nested ternary operators, then you're probably using it inappropriately, too.  Occasionally it will be OK, but not very often.

Answer (score 0):

The ?: operator can be used as a shortcut for an if...else statement. It is typically used as part of a larger expression where an if...else statement would be awkward.

For example:

```
time_t t = time(0);
now = localtime( & t );
greeting = "Good" + ((now->tm_hour > 17) ? " evening." : " day.");
```

copied from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx